# Windows 7 startup problem in bootcamp

Tags: windows, bootcamp

My windows 7 partition has a startup problem. The system will not start, even in safe mode, it gives me an error. If it were a windows machine, I would probably put in a startup disk, but I do not have one. I can read the files on the drive from the mac side, but the system will not start in windows. It worked great before this but it must have gotten a virus. help

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: maybe try making an image of the Windows partition with WinClone and then try to restore it - it will offer to recreate the "boot files" - if I remember correctly. Maybe there is a shorter way, this experiment will take a few hours... like I said, just an idea, double check if WinClone really offers to recreate the boot files.